# Request and Response between two projects

Tags: angularjs, url, client-side, server-side

I'm trying to work on 2 projects. The first one is mainly for client side (AngularJS+MVC) development and second is server side, including web APIs. I want to use web APIs as controllers.

I set the server side project as start-up project. Then set its URL (localhost:..../) as the URL of the controller, then ran the project. After that with the view in the browser, I ran my view, too. (From the client project). The request correctly gets to the API controller from the second project, but I didn't reserve any Response. I guess the problem is the difference between URLs.

What is your opinion? And what should I do, then?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of response are you getting?  200 (OK) status or something else? you might be getting cross orgin request error, if you have not enabled CORS on the web api and you are making the api request from the client side of the Angular project.

Comment: I checked in debug mode in browser and I saw the length of result is 744 characters. But the response is empty.

Comment: Have you checked what the api returns when making a call from a rest client like POSTMAN(chrome plugin) instead of from the angular client. That is testing the API itself and checking what is the response returned. If you are seeing the data you expect returned this way. That means your api is fine. The issue is in calling your api from the angular client.

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:.......'; is therefore not allowed access. But I was set header as you said. what should I do in my web API project?

Comment: You need to enable CORS on the api side . The following article is useful if you need to know to enable CORS. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api  . public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CORSAllowedOrigins"], "*", "*")
            {
                SupportsCredentials = true,
                ExposedHeaders = { "Location" }
            });

Answer (score 0):

Please don't mind my poor English.

Are two projects served on the same domain? If not, there maybe a cross origin request error. You can fix it by adding some headers, like this:

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,PATCH');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With');`

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:.......' is therefore not allowed access. But I was set header as you said. what should I do in my web API  project?

Comment: you should set these headers in your response, not request.